# vectors containing pointers to polymorphic classes

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, polymorphism

I have some troubles understanding how to correctly use vectors of pointers in relation with polymorphic classes. 
Suppose I have a polymorphic structure:

***Parent class***

```
class Bumper {

    protected:
    double mu_;

    public:
    Bumper(){};
    Bumper(double mu):mu_(fabs(mu)){};

    void Set_mu(double mu){mu_=mu;};
    virtual void Bounce (Ball & myB)const{myB.change_speed(-sqrt(mu_));};

};
```

***Child class***

```
class ThresholdBumper : public Bumper {

    protected:
    double eps_;

    public:
    ThresholdBumper(double eps):Bumper(1.5), eps_(eps){};

    virtual void Bounce (Ball & myB){
            if(myB.energy()<eps_){Set_mu(1); Bumper::Bounce(myB); Set_mu(1.5); return;};
            Bumper::Bounce(myB);
    };


};
```

***Function***

```
void flipper (Ball & myB, vector<Bumper*> & Obst){
    for(int i=Obst.size()-1; i>=0; i--){
            Obst[i]->Bounce(myB);
    };
};
```

*change_speed()* is a void function changing private parameters inside the class Ball, and *energy()* is a scalar function.
This code:

```
 vector<Bumper*> myBumpers1(10);

 for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
       myBumpers1[i]=new ThresholdBumper(drand48()*5);
 };

 flipper(myBalls2,myBumpers1);
```

does not work, since Bumper::Bounce() gets called in the "flipper" function. Which means that the function seems to not recognize that there is polymorphism. Can someone explain me why? In particular, redifining the function as:

***Function'***

```
 void flipper(Ball & myB, vector<Bumper*>::iterator begin, vector<Bumper*>::iterator end){
    vector<Bumper*>::iterator it;
    for(it=end-1; it!=begin; --it){
            (*it)->Bounce(myB);
    };
};
```

makes everything work well, as expected. What is the difference exactly?

Comment: A little offtopic maybe, but keep in mind that when you deal with polymorphism, make sure to declare a destructor of a base class as `virtual`.

Comment: Also - I noticed that in the first definition of `flipper` function you define it to take 2 arguments, but you call it using 3 (notice the **0** in `flipper(myBalls2,myBumpers1,0);`). Typo?

Comment: yes, that's a typo. In the original code it required 3 arguments, but since it was unnecessary for my question I erased it (or i thought so). Thank you for the advice anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your child class actually declares separate `Bounce` function instead of overriding base class `Bounce`. Notice that in base class it is declared as `const`. You should redeclare it in child class as

```c++
void Bounce (Ball & myB) const override {
```

`override` keyword ensures that a virtual function of base class is being overriden

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But in this case I won't be able to define it as const, since it modifies protected members of the class, right? This means that the kind of polymorphism (with const on one function and not in the other) I developed is generally impossible to use unless you are using iterators?

Comment: `const` modificator is a part of non static member function signature, so that kind of polymorphism is not possible. Note that if it was possible then calling `const` virtual function of base class would result in a call of `non const` function.

Comment: Actually `override` is not a keyword in C++. It's a hint for a compiler to produce errors if the fuction marked as `override` *does not override* any function in parent class.